# Is there a way to work with Angular2 CLI and fontgen-loader?

Tags: angular, svg, webpack, angular2-cli

I'm kinda new to angular2 , webfonts and webpack. 
Many people recommended me to work with the Angular2 CLI - which is very convenient. 
But now, I need to work with webfonts and (other) many people told me to work with "fontgen-loader".

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontgen-loader

I noticed that the Angular2 CLI not working **directly** with webpack and in the "fontgen-loader" documentation it's said that I need to work with the "webpack.config.js" file which is not exist in the Angular2 CLI system.

Is there a way to work with "fontgen-loader" and Angular2 CLI? 
If yes - what I need to do in order it to work?
If no - is there an alternative way to work with webfonts and Angular2 CLI?

p.s

I bumped into this thing but for some reason the /*.svg cause to an error in my terminal. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/icon-font-generator

Thanks